# MVC Security problems in my application - Best strategy for separating logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I feel like the biggest idiot - I thought only `ActionResults` were sent back to the client. For this reason, I had a load of "helper" methods in my controller.

I just tried accessing them via a URL and I swear I  almost went crazy when I saw they can be reached! ... Luckily, no one else has discovered this yet.

One such method I have, that I call over and over again is :

```
public User GetCurrentUser()
{    
    User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
    return user;
}
```

I have just created a folder called "Logic" inside my Models folder and I am attempting to separate the code - I was just wondering what the best strategy is for calling code, namespaces and more?

In the above example, I am using `User.Identity.Name` which only inherits from `Controller`. If I add this, I am back to stage one!

Thanks to Darin Dimitrov, I now know about the `[NonAction]` Attribute - which, adding to these methods does **exactly** what I need/fixes the security problem, however, many of these Methods are used in different controllers and I know it would be best if I can separate the logic from the controllers. I am just not sure what the best way to go about it is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction before I start pulling all my hair out!?

Comment: What uses these helper methods? Can you just make them `private`?

Comment: @Graham Clark - I can, but, there are various ones that I would like to use in more than one Controller... At the moment, I have duplicated the code across controllers and have been meaning to separate them for a long time so I can have them in one place - just not sure on the best strategy.... Based on this, I am not entirely sure private will work :/

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute.

---

UPDATE:

Or you could use the [`[NonAction]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.nonactionattribute.aspx) attribute or make the method private. But the best practice in this case would be to simply move this logic out of your controller. A controller should contain only controller actions. Other logic should be placed in its respective layers.

Comment: I am not sure that this is exactly what I want - I have [Authorize] already as this is meant to be for members only, but, these are methods that should not be accessed **AT ALL** from the browser, only other methods - therefore, I know I need/should separate the classes, just not sure the best strategy.

Comment: Or the `private` modifier. :)

Comment: @wil, you could use the `[NonAction]` attribute in this case. But honestly controllers should contain only controller actions. Nothing else. Everything else doesn't belong to a controller and I would strongly recommend you to move it out from your controller to the corresponding layer of your application.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I completely fully agree... and that is what I really need advice doing! It is just that some of these helper methods use things such as Server.MapPath, which, (As far as I can see) to be inherited from the Controller Class... So, I just do not know where to go from here/how to separate.

Comment: Well you could use Server.MapPath in the controller to obtain the information you need and then pass the information into your helper/service class.

Comment: @WooHoo - I understand and I am thinking that this will be the quickest solution to separate the methods, however, this will be rather annoying - For example, I have a method that creates a random folder and returns the string/name of it... I ideally don't want to start passing variables around when it worked fine before.... I now know that [NonAction] will work 100% fine, but, I know that this isn't exactly best practice and I would like to do this the proper way!

Comment: I have updated the question to try and be a bit clearer... +1 and thanks - [NonAction] gets around the immediate security problem, so, I am happy - but... I know this isn't best, and, I really want to follow best practices... just not sure how to do it!

Comment: @wil, in the case of the method you showed in your example you could modify it so that it takes a string parameter representing the username. Then from the controller call it like this: `_repository.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);`.