# Trying to separate logic from controller in an MVC Entity Framework app - What is happening here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, methods, entity-framework-4.1

Based on my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822869/mvc-security-problems-in-my-application-best-strategy-for-separating-logic), I have tried to separate the business logic from my controller completely.

This however has left a problem which I understand why, but not how to fix.... And, I do not understand why it is doing what is doing.

In my controller, I had the following:

```
public User GetCurrentUser()
{    
    User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
    return user;
}
```

I now know about `[NonAction]` which fixes the security concern - however, I know this doesn't follow best practices of not having any non controller stuff in a controller. For this reason, I moved to a new class and modified it to the following:

```
public User GetCurrentUser(string name)
{    
    User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == name);
    return user;
}
```

I have an edit method which before simply set various fields in the user object, then called `db.SaveChanges()`. This however is now causing issues - I believe it is due to calling the command on a `db` object that doesn't actually have the object loaded.

But, the part that I really do not understand is when I am redirected back to the home page and perform `GetCurrentUser()` again, I am presented with the edited details I changed... These are not stored in the database and it is only when I restart the application it goes back to the database results.

I am finding this very confusing! What is happening here and where are the object being stored?

And, how do I fix it? I have tried making the new Class's db function public and calling it's `SaveChanges()` method, but, this is resulting in the same problem - data that is not being saved to the database.

Anyway, quite frankly, I really liked calling it via just `GetCurrentUser()`, I wanted this due to the fact I wanted to change the way the user was loaded in the future - but, now that I have to call it via `GetCurrentUser(User.Identity.Name)`, and make other modifications, I think it wouldn't be that much harder to just skip on the method and call the Lambda query directly instead... It just seems it will save a lot of trouble.

Comment: Can you post your editing method and also your calling code from HomeController to invoke `GetCurrentUser()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the detail in your question, you need to make sure you attaching your Entity object e.g `db.Users.Attach(updatedUser)`
And then change its state
e.g `db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(updatedUser, EntityState.Modified)`

Before you call `db.SaveChanges()`

Comment: Thank you - I have gone down a different route as adding this code each time along with the other substitutes I have had to make actually makes for more code. Anyway, for the actual problem, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The edit functions I've written for my MVC app usually have one more line of code before I call SaveChanges:

```
 _db.ApplyCurrentValues(OriginalEntity.EntityKey.EntitySetName, NewEntity);
 _db.SaveChanges();
```

Also, maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't this (below) be a simpler way to update the user information in the database?

```
Membership.UpdateUser();
```

As for the reason why the non-database data is still showing up for you, I *think* that is because when you call GetCurrentUser it caches information on the client side. I'm sure someone with more experience here can give a more detailed (or more correct answer) on that part.